# PySpark find if pattern in one column is present in another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I've two pyspark data frames. One contain FullAddress field(say col1)  and another data frame contains name of city/town/suburb in one of the columns(say col2). I want to compare col2 with col1 and return col2 if there is a match.

Additionally, the suburb name could be a list of suburb name.

*Dataframe1 that contains full address*

```
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|Postcode|District|City/ Town/ Suburb                                        |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|2000    |Sydney  |Dawes Point, Haymarket, Millers Point, Sydney, The Rocks  |
|2001    |Sydney  |Sydney                                                    |
|2113    |Sydney  |North Ryde                                                |
+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+



+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|FullAddress                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|BADAJOZ ROAD NORTH RYDE 2113, NSW, Australia               |
| HAY STREET HAYMARKET 2000, NSW, Australia                 |
| SMART STREET FAIRFIELD 2165, NSW, Australia               |
|CLARENCE STREET SYDNEY 2000, NSW, Australia                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to have something like this

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------++-----------+
|FullAddress                                                |suburb      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------++-----------+
|BADAJOZ ROAD NORTH RYDE 2113, NSW, Australia               |NORTH RYDE  |
| HAY STREET HAYMARKET 2000, NSW, Australia                 |HAYMARKET   |
| SMART STREET FAIRFIELD 2165, NSW, Australia               |NULL        |
|CLARENCE STREET SYDNEY 2000, NSW, Australia                |SYDNEY      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------++-----------+
```

Comment: Do you need to join the dataframes on Postcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `DataFrames` -

*DataFrame 1:* `DataFrame` containing the complete address.

*DataFrame 2:* `DataFrame` containing the base data - `Postcode`, `District` & `City / Town / Suburb`.

The aim of the problem is to extract the appropriate `suburb` for `DataFrame 1` from `DataFrame 2`. Though OP has not explicitly specified the `key` on which we can join the two DataFrames, but `Postcode` only seems to be the reasonable choice.

```
# Importing requisite functions
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,regexp_extract,split,udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
```

Let's create the `DataFrame 1` as `df`. In this `DataFrame` we need to extract the `Postcode`. In Australia, all the post codes are [4 digit long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_Australia), so we use [regexp_extract()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) to extract 4 digit number from the `string` column.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('BADAJOZ ROAD NORTH RYDE 2113, NSW, Australia ',),
                                 ('HAY STREET HAYMARKET 2000, NSW, Australia',),
                                 ('SMART STREET FAIRFIELD 2165, NSW, Australia',),
                                 ('CLARENCE STREET SYDNEY 2000, NSW, Australia',)],
                                 ('FullAddress',))
df = df.withColumn('Postcode', regexp_extract('FullAddress', "(\\d{4})" , 1 ))
df.show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------------------------+--------+
|FullAddress                                  |Postcode|
+---------------------------------------------+--------+
|BADAJOZ ROAD NORTH RYDE 2113, NSW, Australia |2113    |
|HAY STREET HAYMARKET 2000, NSW, Australia    |2000    |
|SMART STREET FAIRFIELD 2165, NSW, Australia  |2165    |
|CLARENCE STREET SYDNEY 2000, NSW, Australia  |2000    |
+---------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Now, that we have extracted the `Postcode`, we have created the `key` to join the two `DataFrames`. Let's create the `DataFrame 2`, from which we need to extract respective `suburb`.

```
df_City_Town_Suburb = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(2000,'Sydney','Dawes Point, Haymarket, Millers Point, Sydney, The Rocks'),
                                             (2001,'Sydney','Sydney'),(2113,'Sydney','North Ryde')],
                                             ('Postcode','District','City_Town_Suburb'))
df_City_Town_Suburb.show(truncate=False)

+--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|Postcode|District|City_Town_Suburb                                        |
+--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|2000    |Sydney  |Dawes Point, Haymarket, Millers Point, Sydney, The Rocks|
|2001    |Sydney  |Sydney                                                  |
|2113    |Sydney  |North Ryde                                              |
+--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Joining the two `DataFrames` with `left` join -

```
df = df.join(df_City_Town_Suburb.select('Postcode','City_Town_Suburb'), ['Postcode'],how='left')
df.show(truncate=False)
+--------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|Postcode|FullAddress                                  |City_Town_Suburb                                        |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|2113    |BADAJOZ ROAD NORTH RYDE 2113, NSW, Australia |North Ryde                                              |
|2165    |SMART STREET FAIRFIELD 2165, NSW, Australia  |null                                                    |
|2000    |HAY STREET HAYMARKET 2000, NSW, Australia    |Dawes Point, Haymarket, Millers Point, Sydney, The Rocks|
|2000    |CLARENCE STREET SYDNEY 2000, NSW, Australia  |Dawes Point, Haymarket, Millers Point, Sydney, The Rocks|
+--------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Splitting the column `City_Town_Suburb` into an array using [split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189088/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array-in-pyspark-dataframe) function -

```
df = df.select('Postcode','FullAddress',split(col("City_Town_Suburb"), ",\s*").alias("City_Town_Suburb"))
df.show(truncate=False)
+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|Postcode|FullAddress                                  |City_Town_Suburb                                          |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|2113    |BADAJOZ ROAD NORTH RYDE 2113, NSW, Australia |[North Ryde]                                              |
|2165    |SMART STREET FAIRFIELD 2165, NSW, Australia  |null                                                      |
|2000    |HAY STREET HAYMARKET 2000, NSW, Australia    |[Dawes Point, Haymarket, Millers Point, Sydney, The Rocks]|
|2000    |CLARENCE STREET SYDNEY 2000, NSW, Australia  |[Dawes Point, Haymarket, Millers Point, Sydney, The Rocks]|
+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally creating a [UDF](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) to check each and every element of the array `City_Town_Suburb` if it exists in the column `FullAddress`. If there exists a one, we return that immediately, else `None` is returned.

```
def suburb(FullAddress,City_Town_Suburb):
   # Check for the case where there is no Array, otherwise we will get an Error
   if City_Town_Suburb == None:
      return None
   # Checking each and every Array element if it exists in 'FullAddress',
   # and if a match is found, it's immediately returned.
   for sub in City_Town_Suburb:
      if sub.strip().upper() in FullAddress:
         return sub.upper()
   return None
suburb_udf = udf(suburb,StringType())
```

Applying this `UDF` -

```
df = df.withColumn('suburb', suburb_udf(col('FullAddress'),col('City_Town_Suburb'))).drop('City_Town_Suburb')
df.show(truncate=False)
+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
|Postcode|FullAddress                                  |suburb    |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
|2113    |BADAJOZ ROAD NORTH RYDE 2113, NSW, Australia |NORTH RYDE|
|2165    |SMART STREET FAIRFIELD 2165, NSW, Australia  |null      |
|2000    |HAY STREET HAYMARKET 2000, NSW, Australia    |HAYMARKET |
|2000    |CLARENCE STREET SYDNEY 2000, NSW, Australia  |SYDNEY    |
+--------+---------------------------------------------+----------+
```